# How to find 5e DM materials online, preferably for free?

Tags: dnd-5e

The reason I'm asking this is because of, quite simply, the *Monster Manual.* As a DM, I know I'm probably gonna need it, but not all the time. So instead of buying it physically, I want to see if there is a free online way to access it. If you could also find a way to get *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* the same way, that would be great as well. I'm not talking about campaign books by the way. Someone suggested [How do I find quest books for sale?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71141/how-do-i-find-quest-books-for-sale) as a alternative question with answers, but again, I'm not talking about campaign books (yet)

Comment: FWIW aside from monster stat blocks the MM also contains many pieces of lore on the various creatures so I’d definitely recommend getting it if you’re going to be DMing often.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DnD 5e materials excluding the Basic Rules and a few supplementary documents such as Unearthed Arcana playtest materials are commercial products sold by their creators. You are unlikely to get them for free except by illegal means, which I do not endorse. You could check your local libraries for borrowing copies of such books, and if you live in a country with permissive copyright laws you might even be allowed to scan the book for later personal, non-commercial use. Consider your local legislation before acting.

Another alternative is having shared access to DnDBeyond from a friend or other contact. If you are registered as a part of their campaign, you can freely access any content they have purchased on DnDBeyond.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. That helps. I'm definitely not gonna go illegal with this :)